# Яндекс Метрика и Гугл Аналитикс. Кому из них верить?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, яндекс-метрика

Яндекс Метрика и Гугл Аналитикс. Кому из них верить?

4 Августа посетители уникальные ЯМ - 123, ГА - 148
5 Августа посетители уникальные ЯМ - 81, ГА - 101

Иногда цифры совпадают

Comment: А время то какое выставлено? Вероятно, там таймзоны в настройках аккаунта разные.

Comment: @Suvitruf сейчас попробую найти...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проанализировав все данные [сайта](https://israel-escorts.com), особенно логи сервера, выбор сделан в пользу GA, так как ЯМ не умеет теперь нормально считать пользователей из Украины, печально однако...